# How can I use "continue" or "break" in match arms, within a for loop?

Tags: loops, rust, pattern-matching

I'm trying to do something like:

```
const CONF_PATHS: [&'static str; 2] = ["/etc/foo.conf", "./foo.conf"];
...
    let conf = for path in CONF_PATHS {
        let load_result = fs::read_to_string(path);
        match load_result {
            Ok(json) => {
                let parse_result: Result<Conf, serde_json::Error> = serde_json::from_str(&json);
                match parse_result {
                    Ok(conf) => conf,
                    Err(err) => {
                        warn!("conf parse failure: {}", err);
                        continue
                    }
                }
            },
            Err(err) => {
                warn!("conf load failure: {}", err);
                continue
            }
        }
    };
```

but the compiler (understandably) complains:

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
  --> foo/src/main.rs:34:25
   |
30 | /                 match parse_result {
31 | |                     Ok(conf) => conf,
   | |                                 ---- this is found to be of type `Conf`
32 | |                     Err(err) => {
33 | |                         warn!("conf parse failure: {}", err);
34 | |                         continue
   | |                         ^^^^^^^^ expected `Conf`, found `()`
35 | |                     }
36 | |                 }
   | |_________________- `match` arms have incompatible types
```

(I was hoping that `continue` would be treated like `todo!()` and not need to match.)

- Is it possible to compose loops and matches in any way?
- Is there a way of "returning" a value to an enclosing scope, without wrapping that whole scope in a function?

A workaround as a separate function, which illustrates the intent, is:

```
const CONF_PATHS: [&'static str; 2] = ["/etc/foo.conf", "./foo.conf"];
const DEFAULT_CONF: Conf = Conf { report_interval: 5 };

/* Load configuration, or use default configuration. */
fn load_conf_or_default() -> Conf {
    for path in CONF_PATHS {
        let load_result = fs::read_to_string(path);
        match load_result {
            Ok(json) => {
                let parse_result: Result<Conf, serde_json::Error> = serde_json::from_str(&json);
                match parse_result {
                    Ok(conf) => return conf,
                    Err(err) => {
                        warn!("conf parse failure: {}", err);
                        continue
                    }
                }
            },
            Err(err) => {
                warn!("conf load failure: {}", err);
                continue
            }
        }
    }
    DEFAULT_CONF
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `for` is not meant to be used in this context. `for` always returns `()`, where you need it to return a value.

You are looking for the first non-error value in a list after a function has been applied, so instead of `for`, you could use `find_map`, something like this:

```rust
fn load_conf_or_default() -> Conf {
    let load_conf = CONF_PATHS.iter().find_map(|&path| {
        let load_result = fs::read_to_string(path);
        match load_result {
            Ok(json) => {
                let parse_result: Result<Conf, serde_json::Error> = serde_json::from_str(&json);
                match parse_result {
                    Ok(conf) => Some(conf),
                    Err(err) => None,
                }
            },
            Err(err) => {
                None
            }
        }
    });
    match load_conf {
        Some(conf) => conf,
        None => DEFAULT_CONF,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not the `continue` that is the problem. It is indeed treated like `todo!()`. The problem is the outer `match`. Since it is not an expression but a statement, it has to return `()`. You can e.g. assign it to a variable:

```rust
let v = match load_result {
    Ok(json) => {
        let parse_result: Result<Conf, serde_json::Error> = serde_json::from_str(&json);
        match parse_result {
            Ok(conf) => conf,
            Err(err) => {
                warn!("conf parse failure: {}", err);
                continue
            }
        }
    },
    Err(err) => {
        warn!("conf load failure: {}", err);
        continue
    }
};
```

Comment: How do I move the `v` value back out of the `for` loop and into the `let conf` variable assignment?  The compiler's not happy with `break conf`.  i.e. the value of the `for` loop expression should be the first successful read of a conf file.  (I have some additional logic outstanding, which will default on failure on the last iteration.)

Comment: @fadedbee You can't `break` with value out of `for` loop (e.g. what if the collection is empty?) You can e.g. assign it to an `Option` variable, or use iterator combinators.

Comment: So, a for-loop as an expression is not a useful thing.   I need to either use a `loop` or go with my current workaround, which is more readable.  Thanks.